# MySQL Workbench GUI problems in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've recently performed a clean install of Ubuntu 14.10. I got Apache, PHP and MySQL from Ubuntu's repositories, then installed MySQL Workbench (6.1.7) from the Ubuntu Software Center. It almost works - there are just two "little" issues, one of which makes the program unusable:

1. After opening the .mwb file it shows in the schema tab: Tables (X items), but no tables are shown below - just Views (X items) etc., which are also not listed at all.
2. For some reason menu in the title bar is triplicated...

Has anyone encountered these issues or has an idea how to solve them? I tried mysql-workbench-community 6.2 from Oracle website, but it's the same.

I posted a screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: There were a lot of issues with MySQL Workbench between 14.04LTS and now.. I would suggest upgrading to either the latest version of Ubuntu or going to the LTS (14.04) ... 14.10 is going to be EOL in a few weeks https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 1):

Just luck that I saw your question. This happened about 2 weeks ago to a friend at work. Since I saw the version was 14.10, I suggested to upgrade to 15.04 and then we could proceed on figuring out what was wrong.

After upgrading, his issues with Workbench were gone. So there might be a couple of things that could be causing this:

- Version of the Libraries used for Workbench in 14.10
- Version of MySQL Workbench (On 15.04 it is 6.2.3)
- Fixes on 15.04 that impacted how Workbench and it's look behaved.

This is how it looks right now for me:

[image]

So my recommendation, before doing anything else, try to upgrade to 15.04 to avoid the End of Life and gain many fixes, enhancements and a newer workbench while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think moving to 14.04 is the best option. I am using Mysql workbench without a problem. 
I think you better to download software package directly from [official](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) site, and go to downloaded location and open with software center.