# MySQL Workbench menu shows doubled

Tags: apt, mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed `mysql-workbench` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using Software Center. It installs MySQL Workbench version 6.0.8.

[image: mysql-workbench version]

In this, the menu is doubled

[image: Workbench menu]

So I decided to upgrade MySQL Workbench. I added a repository provided by [MySQL official website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/) and upgraded it.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

Now MySQL Workbench version is

[image: mysql workbench latest verion 6.2]

Still the menu is duplicated. How can I solve this issue?

**Edit:**

The same question was asked here without any answer:

[MySQL Workbench GUI problems in Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544663/mysql-workbench-gui-problems-in-ubuntu-14-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This multiple menu problem is fixed in mysql workbench version 6.3.3. I installed the new version found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
I installed the following version ***Ubuntu Linux 14.10 (x86, 64-bit), DEB.***

**NOTE:** Am am running Ubuntu 15.04. However, I installed the 14.10 version and it works just fine.

**:END UPDATE**

If you look closely, the menu is not actually doubled. It is actually two separate menus. The first menu is specific to the *MySQL Connections* home page. The second menu is specific to your open database connection. For example, if you open mysql-workbench, at first you'll only see one menu. Then, if you open a database connection and display an SQL worksheet, the second menu is displayed.

I would probably classify this as a bug because of the redundancy of the two separate menus. However, if you'd like to change the menus, you certainly do so by editing the XML for them here: `/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/main_menu.xml`.

One way to do this is to run:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/main_menu.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/680326/215357) by [Milosz Bodzek](https://askubuntu.com/users/434768/milosz-bodzek) solved my problem.
His solution was to put `export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` at the top of the mysql-workbench script file.

[image: Screenshot of Terminal]