# MySql workbench app's menu bar shows duplicate options

Tags: unity, 15.04, mysql

After I installed some updates, MySQL-workbench app's Menu bar is showing duplicate menu entries.

[image]

The same issue was there for GIMP as well. But clean-remove and installing back again solved this problem.

Please let me know if there is any alternative to resolve this issue (If possible permanently), other than remove-and-install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `mysql-workbench` script (usually located in `/usr/local/bin`).

Edit it and put `export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` at the top of the file, save. That's it.

Comment: It was located at `/usr/bin` in my case.

This enabled an in-app Menu-bar, instead of Ubuntu style Menu-bar (as part of title bar), works for me. Thanks a lot :)